# What should I be studying if I want to calculate correlation between data sets?

Tags: statistics, self-learning, machine-learning

I'm building an app that brings in data from multiple API's (Stripe, Google Analytics, Github). I'd want to be able to analyze the different sets of data against each other if at all possible and draw meaningful conclusions based on correlations.

For example, I'd like to analyze monthly pageviews of  against revenue for those months and to find how strongly said page relates to my revenue. I want to  train a model to detect based on previous data when there are significant fluctuations in that data. Such that if suddenly my website dipped 40% in revenue, I can analyze all my analytics and revenue data to find the strongest correlation.

What kind of math should I be looking into? The last I studied math was in high school many years ago. I'm not sure what I should even look for.

Comment: Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Quote from wiki: "In restricted circumstances, regression analysis can be used to infer causal relationships between the independent and dependent variables. However this can lead to illusions or false relationships, so caution is advisable;[1] for example, correlation does not imply causation."

Comment: @LuisVera : maybe the [wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence) can be useful too here for a fast check of independence ?